# How to create formula in excel that can iterate in specific range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to fill down 10 cells with value from `B10` cell:

```
='Disconnect Minor Reason List'!$B$10
```

Then I want to get another 10 cells with value from `B11` cell, then another 10 from `B12` and so on. 
Is it a possible in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach** (better one, since it's not volatile):

- write formula in `E10` cell: `=B10`
- write formula in `E11` cell: `=INDEX($B$10:$B$12,1+INT(COUNTA($E$10:E10)/10))`

and drag it down.

**Second approach:** (if you'd like to use single formula)

use this formula in `E10` and drag it down:

```
=INDEX($B$10:$B$12,1+INT((ROW()-ROW($E$10))/10))
```